# ComboBox Text not Binding to DataGrid SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, datagrid

I want the `Text` property of my `ComboBox` to change based on the `SelectedItem` of a `DataGrid`. I have tried in code-behind and in `XAML` and have got to this;

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="contactEmployeeComboBox" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.EmployeeName, ElementName=contactsDataGrid, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="5">
```

however the `Text` still does not change when I select another item from the `DataGrid`. How can I correctly bind the `ComboBox`?

**EDIT:** `DataGrid`

```
private void FillContactsDataGrid()
{
    var selectedCompany = dataGrid.SelectedItem as CompanyModel;
    var Contacts = new ObservableCollection<ContactsModel>();
    var waitWindow = new PleaseWait();

    var ContactTypes = new ObservableCollection<TypeOfContact>();
    var contactService = new ContactsDataService();
    ContactTypes = contactService.GetContactTypesDBF();

    cancelAddContactButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    cancelUpdateContactButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    var contactsDataService = new ContactsDataService();
    Contacts = contactsDataService.HandleContactSelect(companyID);           
    ContactsICollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Contacts);
    contactsDataGrid.ItemsSource = ContactsICollectionView;

    //Contacts = await ReturnContacts(Convert.ToInt32(selectedCompany.ID)); removed as tabs were jumping back to companies
}
```

Comment: set to `Text="{Binding SelectedItem.EmployeeName, ElementName=contactsDataGrid, Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: is it MVVM or code-behind? put please your code of filling `DataGrid` and `ComboBox` of `DataGrid`

Comment: `ComboBox` isn't filled, it only has two Items in it which I hard-code in. I've added the code for `DataGrid` though I think it's unrelated...

Comment: am I right that it is MVVM applcation?

Comment: @StepUp no it is code-behind

Answer (score 0):

**[Binding.Mode Property - gets or sets a value that indicates the
 direction of the data flow in the binding.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode(v=vs.110).aspx)**

Try to set to `TwoWay` like that:

```
<ComboBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.EmployeeName, ElementName=contactsDataGrid, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

[As MSDN says:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **TwoWay.**    Causes changes to either the source property or the target
>   property to automatically update the other. This type of binding is
>   appropriate for editable forms or other fully-interactive UI
>   scenarios.

**Update:**

**YourModel:**

```
public class YourModel
{
    public string TitleField { get; set; }    
}
```

**CodeBehind:**

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FillDataGrid();
    }

    private void FillDataGrid()
    {
        ObservableCollection<YourModel> coll = new ObservableCollection<YourModel>();
        for (int start = 0; start < 10; start++)
        {
            coll.Add(new YourModel(){TitleField="Title " +  
            start.ToString());                                
        }
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = coll;
        comboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "TitleField";
        comboBox.ItemsSource = coll;
    }


    private void dataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {            
        var dataGrid = e.Source as DataGrid;
        var currentIndex = dataGrid.Items.IndexOf(dataGrid.CurrentItem);            
        comboBox.SelectedIndex= currentIndex;
    }
```

**Your XAML:**

```
<StackPanel>
   <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" SelectionChanged="dataGrid_SelectionChanged" />
   <ComboBox  Name="comboBox"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Still no luck unfortunately, besides I actually want `OneWay` so that the `DataGrid` is not updated on the changing of the `ComboBox`.

Comment: @CBreeze feel free to ask any question